# Calculating complexities of both time and space

Tags: complexity-theory

```
int foo2(int k) //function defining
{
 int x=0;     // O(1)
 while(n>0)    // O(log(n))
 {
  int i;      // another O(log(n)) because its inside the loop 

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)     // O((n+1)*log(n)) this loop happens inside the while loop
  {
   x += i;      //  O(n*log(n)) happens inside the while and for loops
  }

  n /=2;       // O(log(n) because its inside the while loop and outside the for loop
  }
}
```

I am trying to compute the complexity of the following code so my answer after my analysis is that the complexity of time is O(n*log(n)). can you check if my steps are correct and if they are not can you tell me whats wrong? also is it 
because there are no arrays or strings here then the complexity of space is O(1)?

Comment: This looks like homework, it's called Stack Overflow, not Homework Overflow :)

Comment: Im new here,so whats the problem with asking about somethings in my homework?

Comment: You can ask specific questions about homework, but getting people to do it for you isn't ok. This is probably stepping over the lines a little. If you had a specific question that would be ok, but asking for people to check your work and fix any mistakes isn't. Put another way, would you be happy for your professor to see this linked to your name? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework

Comment: You seem to be doing fairly well, but part of learning to solve problems is learning to know when you can be confident you have solved them: some (perhaps most) people are too optimistic that their solution is complete, others are too pessimistic. You need to check your work yourself, using your textbooks / lecture notes, and at some point take the plunge and commit yourself. If you are wrong, you will probably learn more than if had had never committed yourself. And you will give a more honest impression of your abilities!